# If $\det (A+B)= \det (A)$, is $\det(B)$ always zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\det (A+B)= \det (A)$, is  $\det(B)$ always zero?

Considering that if $A=B=I$, the determinant of $(A+B)$ is $4$ and $\det (A)+\det(B)=2$, but I cannot find a counterexample of $\det (A+B)= \det (A)$ with $\det(B)$ different than zero.

Comment: Consider $A = I$ and $B = -2I$, where the dimension is even.

Comment: note that in general you can't say that $\det(A+B) = 4$ when both $A$ and $B$ are the identity matrix. It depends also on their size! So $\det(A+B) = 2^n$...

Answer (score 2):

$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$A=-\frac{1}{2} I \,;\, B= I$$

This example works for square matrices with an even number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of

$$\det(A)=\det(A+B)$$ is give by

- $A$ is invertible and $B=AX$ where $\det(I+X)=1$

or

- $\det(A)=0$ and $B=X-A$ where $\det(X)=0$.

In both cases it is trivial to construct invertible $B$. In the first case, if $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $X$, you need
$$(1+\lambda_1)....(1+\lambda_n)=1$$

and $B$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda_i \neq 0 \forall i$.

In the second case, the problem reduces to finding two non-invertible matrices whose difference is invertible.